# Update field in table for all records using a select statement

Tags: sql

A previous developer created a table that stores the absolute path to files in our server. I want to convert them to relative paths instead.

I already wrote the portion that properly strips the string down to a relative path. My issue is understanding how to basically update each record, with a new version of its own string.

Here is what I originally tried:

```
UPDATE LFRX_Attachments
    SET [File] = (SELECT TOP 1 SUBSTRING([File], PATINDEX('%Files\%', [File]) + 6, LEN([File]))
                     FROM LFRX_Attachments A
                     WHERE [Type] = 4 AND AttachmentId = A.AttachmentId)
```

However, this tanked in epic fashion by just overwriting every record to have the value of the first record in the table. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE LFRX_Attachments
SET [File] = SUBSTRING([File], PATINDEX('Files\', [File]) + 6, LEN([File]))
WHERE [Type] = 4
```

Comment: Talk about a brain fart. I discovered this syntax before reviewing your post. UPDATE A SET A.[File] = ... FROM LFRX_Attachments A. Interesting Thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

From a readability/maintenance standpoint, you're better off selecting for the data you want to alter, then iterating through the result set and updating each record separately.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

UPDATE LFRX_Attachments SET [File] = SUBSTRING([File], PATINDEX('Files\', [File]) + 6, LEN([File]))